# Equivalent of bash "|" in python3

Tags: python-3.x, bash

In bash, you can do `echo a | python -c "print('example:', input())"` and you will get an output of `example: a`. How can you do the same thing in python.

I have tried doing this:

```py
pid = os.fork()
if not pid:
    os.dup2(0, 1)
    os.execv("/usr/local/bin/python3", ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-c", "print('example:', input())"])
else:
    subprocess.call(["echo", "a"])
```

and I have tried this:

```py
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-c", "print('example:', input())"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2.stdin.write(proc1.stdout.read())
```

but both times this error was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

Comment: The second example works for me if I change `"python"` to `"python3"` in `proc2`. That depends on whether Python 2 or Python 3 is set up to be used by default in your OS if the `python` command is invoked.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python-3

Comment: Thanks, that question answered my question. Although I added this line: `open(1, 'wb').write(output)`